# I want to join two array elements and print their values. The output value I am receiving is garbage value

Tags: java, arrays, element

```
    System.out.println("The ip address is in class: ");
    System.out.println("Class C");
    System.out.println("The masked Ip address is:");
    System.out.println(arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + ".0");
```

The above code is working but it is giving me garbage value. I want to print all the elements in the array.

Comment: how does the output look like and what is the data type of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if the IP is 192.168.1.0 
Then you are seeing result as: 1921681.0 
If yes, then you have to print it like this:

```
System.out.println(arr[0] + "." +arr[1] + "." + arr[2] + ".0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print them using for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
    System.out.print(arr[i]);
}
System.out.println(".0");
```

Or, using stream:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: Thanks  for the help

Answer (score 0):

Always print arrays/collections using iterator or loops. Hardcoded array access can lead to errors.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(); 
for(String s:arr){
sb.append(s);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString() + ".0");
```